# Unity splash screen doesn't show the first logo

Tags: unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I have customized my Unity App's splash screen to show three logos, sequentially, for 2 seconds each. However, the first logo always fails to appear. When I open the app, a black screen appears, and when the splash screen comes up it seems that the first logo was "playing" while the screen was black, so it doesn't show. How can I force the logos to show?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your first logo as static splash image ?.  Static splash image will be shown while the engine is loading

Comment: No... it's set up like this: https://i.imgur.com/wialNZ8.png